# Ratings bar css

Tags: css, progress-bar, rating

I am creating a ratings bar for my website and i have a few questions
[Here is the link for the codepen so you can see what I have so far.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ixapz)

what I need is to have two different colors for Likes (green) and dislikes (red). How can I separate these two and have them share the bar. 
So a bit like youtube's rating bar

and the second question

I am using Rails (no rails expertise needed to answer this question) so my code for the likes will be `<%= @movies.likes.size %>` (i.e.: 5000) and dislikes `<%= @movies.dislikes.size %>`(i.e.:3000), using such a high number for a width % wont work.
How can i proportionalize it to fit the bar
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the proportions of likes would be:

```
100*likes/(likes+dislikes)
```

As for the first question, why couldn't you just set the background color of .meter-slim to be red for example?

Comment: Because, say there is one like and 0 dislikes 
It'll be 1% Likes and 0% Dislikes, so most the bar would be red, where as it should be green, this is another issue

Comment: @PMP - In that case, the bar would be 100% likes and 0% dislikes.

Comment: Well no, because I am using `width`, and my rails code (which displays the number of likes) will be a number so if there is one Like it'll display 1% and not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Change the background-color for .meter-slim to the color you want for dislikes and change the background-color for .meter-slim .purple to the color you want for likes ( green in your example ).

You may also want to change the name of that class from purple to something else ( green perhaps ) in both places.

Then for the percentage ( where the 85% is in your example ), use 100*likes/(likes+dislikes)

**EDIT:**
I thought I would add to this based on our comments below.

Like I mentioned, I've only experimented with Ruby a couple of times and that was ten years ago, so my memory is weak.

My idea to put everything in the `<%= %>` was based on your snippets in the question. A better approach, which I should have proposed right away would be to create a variable for the percent of upvotes ( let's call it percent_upvotes ) and then just use `"width: <%= @percent_upvotes %>%"` in your view.

So, you need to calculate that value and store it in percent_upvotes. One way would be to pull out the percentage of upvotes to votes in your SQL statement. I don't know your schema, but it would be something like ...

```
SELECT (upvotes/votes) AS percent_upvotes FROM your_table
```

Or in your Ruby ...

```
percent_upvotes = (movies.upvotes.size.to_f / movies.votes.size.to_f ) * 100.0
```

Comment: What would 100*likes/(likes+dislikes) be? Looking at my Rails code?

Comment: I've only played with Rails a couple of times, but I would try either something like <span class="purple" style="width: <% movies.likes*100/(movies.likes+movies.dislikes) %>%"> ( assuming movies.likes and movies.dislikes are integers )

Comment: Oops, looks like size is what you want. <span class="purple" style="width: <% movies.likes*100/(movies.likes.size+movies.dislikes.size) %>%"> OR <span class="purple" style="width: <% movies.likes*100/(movies.likes+movies.dislikes).size %>%">

Comment: (movies.likes.size*100).to_f / ((movies.likes+movies.dislikes).size).to_f

Comment: This doesnt work at it displays everything 100%

I've changed the database so that the movie has 2 likes and 2 dislikes and all i can see is 100% purple, I was hoping for split purple and split other colour

Comment: I don't write code in Rails, but if you get the math working, you should be okay. Be sure to convert each to a float and then divide likes by the total of likes+dislikes and multiply by 100

Comment: For some reason when I run this code `<% (@movie.upvotes.size).to_f / ((@movie.upvotes+@movie.downvotes).size).to_f %>` outside of the code, nothing shows.

Comment: And It may help to inform you that I also have `<%= @movie.votes.size %>`, which does upvotes + downvotes

Oh Yes upvotes are likes and downvotes are dislikes

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS Frameworks contain CSS Progress Bars natively.

To name a few:

- Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#progress
- Zurb Foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/progress-bars.html

and some CSS resources:

- [CSS3 Progress Bars from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/)
- [Pure CSS Progress Bar from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/pure-css-progress-bar-animated-by-css3)